# Is there a way I can assign a macro to a specific piece of code in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, macros, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ project where I have to output stuff to the terminal and it really bugs me to have to type `cout << << endl;` every time I need to print to the console, because in my keyboard you have to press 3 keys to get the `<`. Is there a keyboard shortcut I could assign to that specific piece of code?

Comment: You can do that, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Do that in your text editor/IDE, and not in the source code. I have one in my editor to expand `cout` (after a keystroke) to `std::cout << ? << std::endl;` with the cursor placed where `?` is.

Comment: Although may physical keyboard layout is a different language, I always switch my keyboard layout to US English, because I like that best for programming (and similar work).  However, this has the disadvantage that you must remember all keys of that keyboard layout, so it is not easy to learn and probably not worth it in your case.

Comment: unrelated to code blocks:  C++ Functions can reduce your typing ... and multiple strings are easily (sometimes trivially) concatenated.  Consider writing (one time per program) a function coutEndl(std::string s);  Inside this, write (for the last time ever?) your cout << s << endl;.  From now on, use coutEndl(s1 + s2 + ...);  Is string concatenation ('+') easier to type?  Is copy paste easy?  Did you know the compiler will auto concatenate the 2 3 char strings "abc" "def"?     Interesting issue.  I wish you luck.

Comment: You might look at the [code snippets plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code_Snippets_plugin). I have not used it, but it looks like it will do what you want -- save the `<<` characters, which can then be pasted into your code with a double-click. If it works for you, be sure to come back and post that as an answer to your own question. (It's not my answer because I have not tried it.)